# RESTful WebService CORS Preflight Channel did not succeed

Tags: c#, web-services, cors

I created a WebService in C#. All GET methods are working without any problems.

Now I need to provide some POST methods. When calling it via C# it works without any problems. Then I tried to write a small html page with JavaScript to call my methods. But there I get a CORS error ("Preflight channel did not succeed").

I already added the following part to my web.config file:

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
</customHeaders>
```

Sadly it is still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can I ask what framework you're using for the APIs?

Comment: Do you handle the HEAD method? Usually browsers do a preflight request with a HEAD method to check the CORS policy only once.

Comment: @Gusman actually it's usually with an `OPTIONS` request. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#How_CORS_works

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yes, you're right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you have here is not really a valid way to handle CORS requests.  The problem is that this will add the CORS headers to **all responses**, but browsers will use an `OPTIONS` request in order to check for CORS headers.  This *would work* **if** you also implement `OPTIONS` requests for all of your API end points.

The better option is to use one of the CORS frameworks, such as this one: [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for ASP.NET WebAPI 2.  This type of framework will intercept the `OPTIONS` request for you and supply the appropriate response without the need for you to manually create 2 routes per endpoint.

Comment: Hey @CodingGorilla,

I just rewrited my project to ASP.NET Web API 2 and now it works without any problems. Thank you.